# What filler words can be used in Korean to buy time in the conversation/show you are thinking?

Tags: grammar, conversation

[This was one of our definition questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/80917#80917). Words like English 'er...', 'well...', 'hmm...', 'like...', examples of some of the words with their definition and use will suffice.

Comment: I’d suggest shortening the question, putting it all in the description, but dropping references to Area 51. As to make the question look more natural when the site go live, but I’m new to private betas, so I may be utterly in the wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a bunch! Not sure if this will be a good answer, and there will certainly be more, but these come to mind right now...

- 그냥 - "Like..."
- 그게 - "That is..."
- 그 - "Uh..." (Hard to come up with an equivalent here)
- 음 - "Um..."
- 아/어 - "Ah.../Uh..."
- 막 - "Just..."

And if we want to kind of extend it a bit

- 어차피 - "Anyway"
- 아무튼 - "Anyway"

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)) also mentions 어 and 그 as short forms.

Comment: I would add 막 ("just") to this list. Hear it all the time.

Comment: @Kaiwa hey good to see you from /r/korean! Good addition, I'll throw it in.